# AWS CloudFormation is stuck on DELETED_FAILED status

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have some AWS CloudFormation stacks which are in the status DELETED_FAILED. There was an issue building these CFTs which caused them to time out originally, and then I attempted to delete them.

When contacting AWS support on a separate issue they mentioned there is a way to clear these up. How can I get remove stacks which are in a DELETED_FAILED status?

Comment: delete them couple of times and they will be gone eventually.

Comment: What does the [event log](https://cdn-enterprise.discourse.org/docker/uploads/default/original/2X/3/3085c761f558562fee2365eec9b24a8df9509eba.png) say?

Comment: I only see the stack that has the status of DELETE_FAILED via the CLI, I can't see it in the AWS console.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Identify the resources that are attached to the stack and delete them manually from AWS web console. 
You can find the resources attached to your stack in the cloud formation stack details. 
And then you should be able to clear the stack in DELETE_FAILED status.

Hope this helps for you.

Comment: What if they're not there? There is a AWS Batch Compute Environment causing my stack to get stuck in DELETE_FAILED due to an `Internal Error` but I don't see the resource in the AWS Batch console.

Answer (score 6):

I deleted a pipeline stack but the stacks it had created could not be deleted because the IAM role no longer existed. Things seem to need to be deleted in a certain order. I redeployed the pipeline and only then was able to delete the stack.

[image]

AWS now also gives the option to exclude resources that prevent deletion.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Did you check [Delete Stack Fails](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/troubleshooting.html#troubleshooting-errors-delete-stack-fails)?

> When stacks are in the DELETE_FAILED state because AWS CloudFormation
>   couldn't delete a resource, rerun the deletion with the
>   **RetainResources** parameter and specify the resource that AWS
>   CloudFormation can't delete. AWS CloudFormation deletes the stack
>   without deleting the retained resource. Retaining resources is useful
>   when you can't delete a resource, such as an S3 bucket that contains
>   objects that you want to keep, but you still want to delete the stack.
>   After you delete the stack, you can manually delete retained resources
>   by using their associated AWS service.

Answer (score 0):

I am using [CDK](https://aws.amazon.com/cdk/) and deployed a stack, then destroyed it.
I ran into the exact **DELETED_FAILED** status issue.

How to fix this status ?

Search "CloudFormation" in the search bar.
Go to Stacks.

Select the DELETED_FAILED stack and press the delete button.

To be really sure all resource have been deleted, if you use **cdk**

```
cdk list
```

> your_stack_name

Then delete this stack

```
cdk destroy your_stack_name
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had also a DELETE_FAIULED status when bootstraping my AWS project. The solution mentioned above did not work for me.
But complete reinstall (also remove the .aws dir in the user directory) works.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/uninstall.html